# Postfix.Dovecot/mysql mailserver setup

Tags: mail-server

I started setting up my mail-server in February. I haven't been able to get it working since. I also haven't been able to get issue specific guidance from google.

My issue as it stands now is as follows:

> Nov 19 14:20:35 Domain postfix/smtp[1134]: < xxx.xxx.x.x[xxx.xxx.x.x]:465: 554 5.4.0 Error: too many hops

Postconf -n output is as follows:

`root@1ag:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_list = xxx.xxx.x.x
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = domain
myhostname = mail.domain.co.za
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliasess
notify_classes = delay, resource, software
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [mail.domain.co.za]:465
smtp_bind_address = xxx.xxx.x.x
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_auth_destination permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = !192.0.2.171/32, 192.0.2.0/24
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, MD5
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp`

Thanks in advance.

---

So, I got the "too many hops" cleared by setting up Amavis and Spamassassin. Not sure how they're related?

The issue now is as follows:

> Domain amavis[6983]: (!)DENIED ACCESS from IP *internal, policy bank ''

and

> Domain postfix/smtp[11593]: 0E6A580207: to=, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1047, delays=1046/0.1/0.04/0, dsn=4.7.5, status=deferred (Cannot start TLS: handshake failure)

Many thanks!

Comment: Your server is using itself as a relayhost, for one thing.

Comment: It should. In order to use port 465 the server should be a relay host together with these settings: smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
                               smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes

Comment: If my relayhost is not set up Postfix switches to port 25 which is closed on my router.

Comment: It looks to me like there'd be bouncing back and forth between the two.  Do you need mail to go through Amavis?  It sounds like Amavis might be at fault, but if you have a different issue than the "too many hops" now that needs its own question

Comment: I've used the method as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862714/problem-with-amavis-and-relayhost-on-postfix/863048. But my problem persists.

Comment: I've started from scratch and configred postfix in stages (like I should have from the start). I did the basic configuration in main.cf and kept master.cf unchanged. I do believe that my SSL configuration is correct. I then just copied the TLS and SASL configuration parameters into the main.cf file. I believe I'm making some solid progress there. My issues now is being unable to get an ehlo response from the smtp server. I've tried Google but none of the advice seems to encompass my problem. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was solved by reconfiguring Postfix on a step by step basis. I have a new issue which pertains to ehlo smtp server verification. As such I will raise a new question and consider this one closed.